# Google map API for finding whether a location inside/outside of circular/rectangular area?

Tags: google-maps

I have to find out whether a given lat/long value is with in a circle/rectangular area whose centre is some lat/long with some fixed radius.

is there any google maps API available for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the documentation - containsLocation

Here is the link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation

Comment: `containsLocation` only works for Polygons, not Circles or Rectangles.